# Eliminating a tab in the view of products

Tags: magento-1.5, products-view, tabs

I need some help in the tabs of the products view, my client had asked me to create some products that are collections of products, and these products doesn’t have a price, and since they don’t have price I have to eliminate a tab in the view of this products, and I’m trying to figure out, I have an idea that in the tabs.phtm file, validate when the product doesn’t have a price, so there use a style with display none to hide the specific tab, but I can’t figure a way to obtain the price of the product it’s been currently watching. So, is there a way I can obtain the price of the product in the tabs.phtml file?

I hope there is, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

You can use this anywhere to get the current product.